# Including fixed factors in Heckit regression

Tags: r, regression, zero

I am working with some zero-inflated fisheries data. I hope to investigate the effect of various bycatch (the non-target portion of catch often discarded at sea) reducing technologies on bycatch in my fishery.

The approach I am currently investigating is using a 2step Heckit regression. I am trying to incorporate two random effect variables (year and vessel) into my model, however, the Heckit model only returns a series of 1's for the coefficient estimates, inf for the Std. Error, zero for the t value, and 1 for the Pr(>|t|) values in the first stage. In the second stage only NAs.

```
library(sampleSelection)

YearF <- factor(Year)
VesselF <- factor(Vessel)

heck1 <- heckit(bcgz ~ lat:long +
                  Effort +
                  YearF +
                  VesselF +
                  Vessel_Length +
                  Season +
                  tech1 +
                  tech2,
                    log(b_c) ~ lat:long +
                  Effort +
                  YearF +
                  VesselF +
                  Vessel_Length +
                  Season + 
                  tech1 +
                  tech2, 
                    method = "2step",
                    data = df1)
```

Has anyone had any luck incorporating fixed effects with many levels into a Heckit regression?

Comment: Can you fit the model with fewer variables? I'm not familiar with the heckit regression you mention, but my experience fitting fisheries data to other zero inflated models is that attempting to fit too many covariates returns NAs or excessively large values for Std. error/std. dev, and you are trying to fit 15 covariates here.

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for your comment. The Heckit is a two-stage regression model, the first stage fits a binary choice (i.e., bycatch or no bycatch), then conditional on a positive response a second regression is fit. At the log(b_c) that is the second stage model. So I have eight covariates being fit in each model. When trying to fit the model just with a single fixed effect of vessel say, it still doesn't like it. So I am wondering if there is a statistical reason why a fixed effect with a high number of levels cannot work with this model.

Comment: can we please have a [mcve] ?

Comment: also, this may belong on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), depending on whether it seems to be more about computation or more about statistics (your question in comment " if there is a statistical reason why a fixed effect with a high number of levels cannot work with this model" sounds more like the latter)

Comment: Is it possible in this regression type to test with fewer input variables? If that works, you might be able to add the additional variables one or two at a time and isolate the reason for the problem. This should be quick to test.